# Node cannot join cluster K8S onprem

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying set up a K8S via VMS and installed the master node successfully.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
master   Ready    control-plane,master   14m   v1.20.1   192.168.5.13   <none>        Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS   4.15.0-124-generic   docker://18.6.3
```

and worker node is also prepared installed ocker, kubeadm, kubectl and kubelet. Firewall disabled, swap is off on master and worker as well.

When I try to run as root on worker following command:

```
kubeadm join 192.168.5.13:6443 --token pk2b8n.i89ywir9vs7cqm7n     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:e9214f892d58196fa6608968f82965113e5dc1928c00d7cf066b52ae4d7037f0     --control-plane
```

Getting the error below

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
error execution phase preflight: 
One or more conditions for hosting a new control plane instance is not satisfied.

failure loading certificate for CA: couldn't load the certificate file /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: open /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt: no such file or directory

Please ensure that:
* The cluster has a stable controlPlaneEndpoint address.
* The certificates that must be shared among control plane instances are provided.


To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

I couldn't handle it. Any help? I'll be really thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took lots of time to find out, I hope it helps someone!

```
vagrant@master:~$ kubeadm token create --print-join-command

kubeadm join 192.168.33.13:6443 --token 7vz9ab.uf2o74um8sqfncv1     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:e9214f892d58196fa6608968f82965113e5dc1928c00d7cf066b52ae4d7037f0
```

Now go to the worker node and run this command again as root

```
root@worker:/ kubeadm join 192.168.33.13:6443 --token 7vz9ab.uf2o74um8sqfncv1     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:e9214f892d58196fa6608968f82965113e5dc1928c00d7cf066b52ae4d7037f0
```

On master, you can verify

```
vagrant@master:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS     ROLES                  AGE   VERSION
master     Ready      control-plane,master   32m   v1.20.1
worker-1   NotReady   <none>                 10s   v1.20.1
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted. It won't give you points but it will be more visible for community.

Comment: @PjoterS  I am able to mark it after 48 hours. I will asap.

Comment: So, what happened here was that you tried to join a new master (HA) because of the `--control-plane` flag, when you removed it worked fine as expected.